# MergeSort Problema Mochila0-1

Tags: java

Quería saber como se implementaría el algoritmo de optimización MergeSort en el código que voy a mostrar a continuación para poder optimizar el algoritmo en sí.

Lo que hace el algoritmo es el problema de la mochila, en la que podemos guardar distintas clases de lingotes. Cada lingote de una clase determinada es fraccionable y tiene cierto peso (real positivo) y valor (real positivo). El algoritmo determina qué cantidad de lingotes de cada tipo debemos coger para maximizar el valor total de lo que cabe en la mochila. La complejidad es de O(n^2) y para mejorar la eficiencia, busco añadir un algoritmo de busqueda como es el MergeSort. Cómo se implementaría?

```html
public class Mochila4{

public static ArrayList<Integer> mochilaLingotes(double[] p, double[] v, double P) {
    int n = p.length; 
    double[] x = new double[n]; 
    ArrayList<Integer> objetos = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    
    // Ordenar los lingotes por valor/peso (en orden descendente)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
            if (v[j]/p[j] > v[i]/p[i]) {
                double tempValor = v[j];
                v[j] = v[i];
                v[i] = tempValor;
                double tempPeso = p[j];
                p[j] = p[i];
                p[i] = tempPeso;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Calcular la cantidad de lingotes a coger
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x[i] = 0.0; 
        
        if (p[i] <= P) {
            x[i] = 1.0; 
            P -= p[i]; 
        } else {
            x[i] = P / p[i]; 
            P = 0.0; 
        }
        
        if (x[i] > 0.0) {
            objetos.add(i); 
        }
    }
    
    return objetos;  
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

La implementación quedaria algo asi. Lo único es que vas a tener que pensar como ordenar también por el valor ya que solo está ordenando con el peso.
Te recomiendo leer muchos ejemplos de como se funciona el merge sort.
Mi código se basa en: Merge Sort in Java de Baeldung.
Y también tienes una buena explicación en el video: Merge Sort | Ordenamiento por mezcla de Chiocode.
No pego los links por que no se si está permitido referenciar por fuera de stackoverflow.
De todas maneras creo que es un buen comienzo:

```
        public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            double[] pesos = {3, 2, 1};
            final double[] valores = {3, 2, 1};
            ArrayList<Integer> objetos = Mochila4.mochilaLingotes(pesos, valores, 5);
        }
    }
```

Clase Mochila4

```
public class Mochila4 {
        public static ArrayList<Integer> mochilaLingotes(double[] pesos, double[] valores, double pesoMax) {
            int n = pesos.length;
            double[] x = new double[n];
            ArrayList<Integer> objetos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
            //ordenarValorPeso(peso, valor, n);
    
            System.out.println("Pesos antes del merge:" + Arrays.toString(pesos));
            mergeSortValorPeso(pesos, valores, pesos.length);
            System.out.println("Pesos despues del merge:" + Arrays.toString(pesos));
    
            // Calcular la cantidad de lingotes a coger
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                x[i] = 0.0;
    
                if (pesos[i] <= pesoMax) {
                    x[i] = 1.0;
                    pesoMax -= pesos[i];
                } else {
                    x[i] = pesoMax / pesos[i];
                    pesoMax = 0.0;
                }
    
                if (x[i] > 0.0) {
                    objetos.add(i);
                }
            }
    
            return objetos;
        }
    
        //La forma de ordenar original
        private static void ordenarValorPeso(double[] peso, double[] valor, int n) {
            // Ordenar los lingotes por valor/peso (en orden descendente)
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                    if (valor[j] / peso[j] > valor[i] / peso[i]) {
                        double tempValor = valor[j];
                        valor[j] = valor[i];
                        valor[i] = tempValor;
                        double tempPeso = peso[j];
                        peso[j] = peso[i];
                        peso[i] = tempPeso;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        // Merge Sort
        // Suponiendo que pesos y valores tienen la misma longitud
        private static void mergeSortValorPeso(double[] pesos, double[] valores, int longitud) {
            if (longitud <= 1) {
                // La condición base verifica si la longitud de la matriz es 1 y simplemente regresará.
                return;
            }
    
            int mitad = longitud / 2;
            double[] izquierdaPesos = new double[mitad];
            double[] derechaPesos = new double[longitud - mitad];
    
            double[] izquierdaValores = new double[mitad];
            double[] derechaValores = new double[longitud - mitad];
    
            //Divide y venceras
            for (int i = 0; i < mitad; i++) {
                izquierdaPesos[i] = pesos[i];
                izquierdaValores[i] = valores[i];
            }
            for (int i = mitad; i < longitud; i++) {
                derechaPesos[i - mitad] = pesos[i];
                derechaValores[i - mitad] = valores[i];
            }
    
            //llamadas recursivas
            mergeSortValorPeso(izquierdaPesos, izquierdaValores, mitad);
            mergeSortValorPeso(derechaPesos, derechaValores, longitud - mitad);
    
            mergeValorPeso(pesos, valores, izquierdaPesos, izquierdaValores, derechaPesos, derechaValores, mitad, longitud - mitad);
        }
    
        private static void mergeValorPeso(double[] pesos, double[] valores, double[] izquierdaPesos, double[] izquierdaValores, double[] derechaPesos, double[] derechaValores, int mitad, int otramitad) {
            int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
            while (i < mitad && j < otramitad) {
                if (izquierdaPesos[i] <= derechaPesos[j]) {
                    pesos[k++] = izquierdaPesos[i++];
                } else {
                    pesos[k++] = derechaPesos[j++];
                }
            }
            while (i < mitad) {
                pesos[k++] = izquierdaPesos[i++];
            }
            while (j < otramitad) {
                pesos[k++] = derechaPesos[j++];
            }
        }
    }
```